# code is correct on Remix but can not run on local,

Tags: remix, blockchain, transactions

I am testing a time dependency question while I don't know why the code can be run successfully on Remix but the error alert is   File "/opt/homebrew/lib/python3.11/site-packages/web3/_utils/contract_error_handling.py", line 135, in raise_contract_logic_error_on_revert
raise ContractLogicError("execution reverted", data=data)
web3.exceptions.ContractLogicError: execution reverted
when i run it locally used a private chain

my code is

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
(!!!this code has a bug just for education aim, do not use it in reality!!!)
pragma solidity ^0.6.8;

contract TimestampDependency {
    uint256 public lastAccessTime;
    uint256 private secretNumber;

    constructor() public{
        lastAccessTime = block.timestamp;
        secretNumber = #whatever;
    }

    function getSecretNumber() public returns (uint256) {
        uint256 currentTimestamp = block.timestamp;
        require(currentTimestamp - lastAccessTime >= 2 minutes, "Access rate limited"); (does the problem happen here?)
        lastAccessTime = currentTimestamp;
        return secretNumber;
    }
}

contract AttackContract{
    TimestampDependency public victim;

    constructor(address payable _addr) public{
        victim = TimestampDependency(_addr);
    }

    event recordSecretNumber(uint256 _number);
    function performTimestampDependencyAttack() public returns(uint256){

        uint256 answer = victim.getSecretNumber();
        emit recordSecretNumber(answer);
        return(answer);
    }
}
```

and the script to launch code is:

```
ignore  code
tx_hash  = contract.functions.performTimestampDependencyAttack().transact({})
```

Comment: There are missing a lots of details. Could you run any contract in the private testnet? Does it support the latest opcodes? Did you check that `contract` is pointing to `AttackContract` contract? Is `victim` properly initialized? are you connected on the right network? Does the transaction have enough gas limit?